# CORS configuration play scala

Tags: scala, playframework, angular7

How can I configure **CORS** to accept **headers** and everything in Play when I connect to it with angular7.
I saw documentation but it doesn't t help me that much.

Is it only configured in `app.conf`?

```
play.filters.cors {
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = null
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
  exposedHeaders = ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]
  preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
```

Comment: Do you have line `play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"` in  your `app.conf`(`application.conf`?).

Comment: thanks for ur help ... i put it in application.conf and it went well i just needed to rebuild (intellij)

Comment: Great to hear that.